# How to make typing sound in Renpy?

Tags: python, renpy

I'm making an Ace Attorney fangame with RenPy. I want to play a "typing" sound when a character is talking.

I tried using this code:

```
define sounds = ['audio/sounds/bip1.mp3','audio/sounds/bip2.mp3','audio/sounds/bip3.mp3']
 
init python:
   def type_sound(event, interact=True, **kwargs):
   if not interact:
      return
 
   if event == "show":
 
      for i in range (50):
         renpy.sound.queue(renpy.random.choice(sounds))
 
   elif event == "slow_done" or event == "end":
       renpy.sound.stop()
```

I already have the sounds mentioned in the `sounds` list.

The problem is that the sounds get played continuously even if there is a pause in the dialogue. For example, in another script, a character says "My name is Walter, Walter Romanng", and I made a pause between the comma and the rest of the sentence; the sound still plays during the pause.

How can I make the typing sounds match the pace and timing of the text on screen?

Comment: There are very few questions about Ren'Py here, and probably very few people who know about it specifically. I would strongly advise you to try the official [forums](https://lemmasoft.renai.us/forums/), [Discord](https://discord.gg/6ckxWYm) or [IRC](http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=renpy) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found what was the problem, when I wanted tu make a "pause", I was using the `{cps =1}` tag but I find the right way to pause the dialogue:

```
"My name is Walter,{w=1} Walter Romanng"
```

this tag wait 1 second and then continue the dialogue, and it's not ignored by the `type_sounds` function.

Answer (score -1):

1.Prepare Typing Sound:
First, make sure you have an audio file (e.g., a .wav or .mp3 file) for the
typing sound that you want to use. Save it in your game's audio folder.

2. Define a Function for Typing Sound:
   Create a function that plays the typing sound. You can place this function in your script or define it in the script.rpy file.

   ## script.rpy

   define sound_typing = [
   ("audio/typing_sound.wav", 0.5),
   ]

Comment: It doesn't really help me... 
I already have the sounds set up like I said, and you just put 
"define sound_typing = [ ("audio/typing_sound.wav", 0.5), ]"
can you explain me what this is doing please ? and also where I have to write this line ? And How i use it ?